# My App created by Buildozer and Kivy is closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Buildozer.spec file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

My app code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton,MDFlatButton,MDRoundFlatButton 
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout as gl
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView as Scroll
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,OneLineListItem
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout as bl
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel 
from math import cos as cs ,sin as sn ,factorial,log as ln,tan as tn , radians,pi,sqrt,exp as e , asin as asn,acos as acn,atan as atn,degrees 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Scl>:
    label_text:label_text
    MDLabel:
        id:label_text
        text: str("")
        size: self.texture_size   
        text_size: self.width,None
        size_hint_y: None
        theme_text_color:'Custom'
        text_color:(1,1,1,1)
        md_bg_color:(1,1,1,1)
        halign:'right'
        font_style:"H3"
        font_size:"27sp"
        bold:True
        
""")


class Scl(Scroll):
    def build(self):
        label_text=ObjectProperty()

class OneLineListItemAligned(OneLineListItem):
    def __init__(self, halign, **kwargs):
        super(OneLineListItemAligned, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = halign
        self.ids._lbl_primary.bold=True
        self.ids._lbl_primary.font_size="25sp"
        self.ids._lbl_primary.text_color=(1,1,1,1)

     
     
class Btn(MDRoundFlatButton):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        self.clr_check=False
        self.result=""
        self.a=""
        self.b=['-','+','*','/','^']
        self.g1=gl(cols=1,padding=20,md_bg_color=(0,0,0,1))
        
        
            
        open('history.txt','a').close()
        #start write the previous history
        self.write()
        #next button clears screen
        
        
        
        self.cl=MDRoundFlatButton(text="All clear",on_release=self.clear,font_size="12sp")
        self.hcl=MDRoundFlatButton(text="Clear",on_release=self.hclear,font_size="12sp")
        
        #result label
        
        self.sv2=Scroll(size_hint=(1,0.25))
        
        self.b1=Scl()
        self.sv2.add_widget(self.b1)
        self.g0=gl(cols=4,rows=5,spacing=10,md_bg_color=(0,0,0,0))
        self.dic={}
        lst=[["ex","(",")","X"],["*","1","2","3"],["-","4","5","6"],["+","7","8","9"],["/",".","0","="]]
        
        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(4):
                self.dic[(row,col)]=MDRoundFlatButton(text=(lst[row][col]),
                on_press=(self.getcheck),
                
                font_size="12sp",
                
                size_hint=(0.1,1)) 
                if lst[row][col] in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','.']:
                    self.dic[(row,col)].text_color=(1,1,0,1)
                else:
                    
                    self.dic[(row,col)].text_color=(1,0,1,1)
            
                    
                
        
            
                    
                self.g0.add_widget(self.dic[(row,col)]) 
                
        # creating buttons 
        
        self.g2=gl(cols=5,spacing=10,md_bg_color=(0,0,0,0))
        self.dic1={}
        self.snd=[["2nd","sin","cos","tan","log"],["1/x","ex","(",")","X"],["^","*","1","2","3"],["√","-","4","5","6"],["%","+","7","8","9"],["π","/",".","0","="]]
        self.lst=[["ex","(",")","X"],["1","2","3","*"],["4","5","6","-"],["7","8","9","+"],[".","0","/","="]]
        
        for row in range(6):
            for col in range(5):
                self.dic1[(row,col)]=MDRoundFlatButton(text=(self.snd[row][col]),
                on_press=(self.getcheck),
            
                text_color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size="12sp",
                size_hint=(0.1,1)) 
                if self.snd[row][col] in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','.']:
                    self.dic1[(row,col)].text_color=(1,1,0,1)
                
                
                else :
                    self.dic1[(row,col)].text_color=(1,0,1,1)
                
                
                self.g2.add_widget(self.dic1[(row,col)])
            
        self.dic[(4,3)].md_bg_color=[1,0.4,0,1]
        self.dic1[(5,4)].md_bg_color=[1,0.4,0,1]
        self.dic[(4,3)].text_color=[1,1,1,1]
        self.dic1[(5,4)].text_color=[1,1,1,1]
        

        self.g1.add_widget(self.sv)
        self.g1.add_widget(self.cl)
        self.g1.add_widget(self.sv2)
        self.g1.add_widget(self.g0)
        
                
        return self.g1
        
    def real(self):
        # pi , factorial, sqrt
        
        self.a=self.a.replace("π","pi")
        
        
        if self.a.count("!")>0:
            temp=self.a[:self.a.index("!")]
            max=0
            if len(temp)==0 or (len(temp)>0 and temp[-1]=="("):
                self.result="Error1"
                self.a=self.result
                
            elif temp[-1]==")":
                dif=temp.count("(")-temp.count(")")
                if dif ==0:
                    max=temp.index("(")
                    
                else:
                    temp=temp[:temp.index("(")]
                    for i in temp:
                        if i in self.b:
                            max=temp.index(i)
            else:
                for i in temp:
                    if i in self.b:
                        max=temp.index(i)
            if len(temp)>0:
                self.a=self.a[:max]+'factorial('+self.a[max:self.a.index("!")]+')'+self.a[self.a.index("!")+1:]
    
        self.a=self.a.replace("√","sqrt")
        self.a=self.a.replace("%","/100")
        
        
    def log(self,num):
        # ln function
        return ln(num,10)
        
        
        
    def write(self):
        #writes history
        self.sv=Scroll()
        self.ml=MDList()
        with open('history.txt','r') as file:
            content=file.read().split('\n')
            content=content[::-1]
        for i in content:
            self.ml.add_widget(OneLineListItemAligned(text=i,
            theme_text_color="Custom",
            text_color=(1,1,1,1),
            halign="right",on_press=self.add))
        self.sv.add_widget(self.ml)
        
        
    def add(self,obj):
        #add the hustory to present function
        try:
            self.a,self.result=obj.text[:obj.text.index(" =")],obj.text[obj.text.index("= ")+2:]
            self.b1.ids.label_text.text=self.result
        except:
            pass
        
    def hclear(self,obj):
        #half clear
        self.result=''
        self.a=""
        self.b1.ids.label_text.text=self.result
        self.check()
        
        
    def clear(self,obj):
        #clear all the text in history
        open("history.txt",'w').close()
        self.ml.clear_widgets()
        self.check()
        
        
    def check(self):
        if self.result=="":
            self.g1.remove_widget(self.cl)
            self.g1.remove_widget(self.hcl)
            self.g1.add_widget(self.cl,index=2)     
        else :
            self.g1.remove_widget(self.hcl)
            self.g1.remove_widget(self.cl)
            self.g1.add_widget(self.hcl,index=2)
            
            
    def getcheck(self,obj):
                if len(self.result)>13:
                    self.result=""
                    self.a=""
                    self.clr_check=False

                if obj.text=="=":
                    atan =lambda num:degrees(atn(num))
                    asin = lambda num: degrees(asn(num))
                    acos= lambda num: degrees(acs(num))
                    log = lambda num: ln(num,10)
                    tan = lambda num:tn(radians(num))
                    sin = lambda num:sn(radians(num))
                    cos = lambda num:cs(radians(num))
                    sec = lambda num:1/cs(radians(num))
                    csc = lambda num:1/sn(radians(num))
                    cot = lambda num:1/tn(radians(num))
                    
                    
                    
                    for i in range(self.a.count('(')-self.a.count(')')):
                        self.a+=')'
                    if len(self.a)>0 and self.a[-1] in self.b:
                        self.a=self.a[:-1]
                    self.a=self.a.replace("()","")
                    temp=self.a
                    self.a=self.a.replace('e^','e')
                    
                    self.a=self.a.replace('^','**')
                    self.real()
                    if len(self.a)==0:
                        self.result='0'
                
                    else:
                        try:
                            self.result=str(round(eval(self.a),6))
                        except Exception as e:
                            self.result="Error"
                            self.a=""
                    
                    if self.result !="Error" and self.a!="" and self.a!=self.result:
                        self.a=self.a.replace("**","^")
                        txt="\n"+temp+" = "+self.result
                        with open("history.txt","a") as file:
                            file.write(txt)
                        self.ml.add_widget(OneLineListItemAligned(text=txt,
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
            text_color=(1,1,1,1),
                        halign="right",on_press=self.add),index=len(self.ml.children))
                
                
                    self.a=self.result 
                    
                    #if len(self.a)>15:
                        #self.result="Error"
                    self.clr_check=True
                elif obj.text=="π":
                    if len(self.a)>0:
                        if self.a[-1] in self.b:
                            self.a+=obj.text
                        else:
                            self.a+='*'+obj.text
                    else:
                        self.a+=obj.text
                    self.result=self.a
                elif obj.text in ['cos','sin','tan','sec','log','cot','csc','√','ln','asin','atan','acos','e'] and len(self.result)<14:
                    if self.clr_check:
                        self.a=""
                    if obj.text=="e":
                        self.a+=obj.text+"^("
                    else:
                        self.a+=obj.text+'('
                    self.result=self.a
                    self.clr_check=False
                    
                elif obj.text==')' and self.a.count('(')==self.a.count(')'):
                    pass
                    
                elif obj.text in self.b and len(self.result)<14:
                    if len(self.a)>0 and self.a[-1]!='^' and self.a[-1] in self.b:
                        self.a=self.a[:-1]+obj.text
                    else:
                        self.a+=obj.text
                    self.clr_check=False
                    self.result=self.a 
                    
                
                elif obj.text=="1/x":
                    self.a+='1/'
                    self.result=self.a
                    
            
                    
                    
                elif obj.text=='(':
                    try:
                        if len(self.a)>0 and self.a[-1] not in self.b:
                            self.a+='*'
                        self.a+='('
                        self.result=self.a
                    except:
                        pass
                    
                
                elif obj.text=="X":
                    self.a=self.a[:-1]
                    self.result =self.a 
                    
                    
                elif len(self.result)>13:
                    self.result=self.result[:13] 
                
                elif obj.text=="ex":
                    
                    self.g1.remove_widget(self.g0)
                    self.g1.add_widget(self.g2)
                    self.dic1[(1,1)].text="Dim" 
                    
                elif obj.text=="Dim":
                    
                    self.g1.remove_widget(self.g2)
                    self.g1.add_widget(self.g0)
                    self.dic[(0,0)].text="ex" 
                    
                elif obj.text == "2nd":
                    
                    self.dic1[(0,0)].text="1st" 
                    self.dic1[(0,1)].text="asin" 
                    self.dic1[(0,2)].text="acos"
                    self.dic1[(0,3)].text="atan"
                    self.dic1[(0,4)].text="ln" 
                    self.dic1[(1,0)].text="e" 
                    self.dic1[(2,0)].text="sec" 
                    self.dic1[(3,0)].text="csc" 
                    self.dic1[(4,0)].text="cot"
                    self.dic1[(5,0)].text="!" 
                    
                elif obj.text =="1st":
                    
                    self.dic1[(0,0)].text="2nd" 
                    self.dic1[(0,1)].text="sin" 
                    self.dic1[(0,2)].text="cos" 
                    self.dic1[(0,3)].text="tan"
                    self.dic1[(0,4)].text="log" 
                    self.dic1[(1,0)].text="1/x" 
                    self.dic1[(2,0)].text="^" 
                    self.dic1[(3,0)].text="√" 
                    self.dic1[(4,0)].text="%"
                    self.dic1[(5,0)].text="π" 
                    
                
                else:
                    if len(self.result)<13:
                        if self.clr_check==True:
                            self.a=""
                            self.clr_check=False
                        self.a+=obj.text
                        self.result=self.a
                self.check()
                if len(self.result)>14:
                    self.b1.font_size="24sp"
                else:
                    self.b1.font_size="30sp"
                self.b1.ids.label_text.text=self.result 
                    
                    
        
MainApp().run()
```

can anyone help me to sort out the error.
The app works fine when I run it on pycharm and there is no errors while creating apk.
But when I tried installing the apk into my phone. It closes without any error.
The app is a calculator where we can get values without any compressions.
I am beginner can anyone help me on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Ty capturing the logcat using `buildozer android deploy run logcat` as described in the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application).

Comment: I was using google colab to create the apk.Does the above command works in google colab.

Comment: Probably not...